# Stable states in Flip Flop

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates

I had seen that flip flop have two stable states 1,0 and 0,1 as output. Why are 1, 1 or 0,0 is not a stable state? Or what do you mean by a stable state here?

Comment: Draw up the logic gates, and the values at their inputs and outputs. Do you notice anything?

Comment: Input 1,1 is unpredictable

Comment: If you include 00 and 11, wouldn't it become a counter?

Comment: A D flip flop will often output an unstable state if both the Reset and Set inputs are active at the same time. If either control signal is removed, the remaining control signal will take effect and the output will be stable again.

Comment: If you mean output when you say "state", then recall that flip-flops have 2 outputs - but one is just the inverse of the other one (or the "complement"). For that reason, if its state is 1 then the other _must_ be a 0, and vice versa